# IntelliJ can't find google-cloud-storage classes

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to use Google cloud storage and I'm following this guide: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library

I'm using Java with Maven, and this is my Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.findwise.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>data-pipeline</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
          <version>0.32.0-beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-all</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.70.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

As you can see I've added the google-cloud-storage dependency. My problem is that the classes used in the Java part of the guide (`Storage`, `StorageOptions`, `Bucket`, `BucketInfo`) are unfindable by IntelliJ. I can't import them. In fact, when I try to import via the absolute path:

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
```

IntelliJ complains that the symbol `google` cannot be resolved. What is wrong here?

Comment: Did you re-import the project into IntelliJ after changing `pom.xml`?

Comment: Is your Intellij project detected as Maven-based? Did you reimport maven dependencies after adding them to pom.xml? You can also try to remove .m2 folder from your home directory and then import them again.

Comment: Karol, no I didn't. What does it mean exactly to re-import the project? Should I close down IntelliJ and then import the project?

Comment: You should have 'Maven Projects' tab on the right. Click it, and then select 'Reimport All Maven Projects' from the bar above the list of projects

Comment: That did the trick! Unfortunately, I had to remove the two other dependencies too since there seems to be some kind of conflict between them.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few places to look:

1. Find your local .m2 repository and navigate to the com.google.cloud dependencies.  If you don't find it, or the JARs aren't there, IntelliJ won't be able to access them.
2. IntelliJ will show you the External Libraries it is using under your source code in the project panel on the left.

If IntelliJ cannot import the class, it suggests that your Maven pull isn't working.